# Самопроизвольное срабатывание кода

Tags: java, циклы

Есть простой пример кода игры-угадайки.

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch, ignore;

        do {
            System.out.print("Введите нужную букву: ");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();

            do {
                ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while (ignore != '\n');

            if (ch == 'a') {
                System.out.println("Правильно!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Неправильно!");
            }
        } while(ch != 'a');
    }
}
```

Работает верно, однако если закомментировать

```
do {
    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
} while (ignore != '\n');
```

То при неверно указанной букве сперва дважды выводится "Введите нужную букву: Неправильно!". Как я понимаю, эта конструкция отбрасывает лишние символы (если, например, ввести вместо 'b' 'bcd'), но почему тогда код срабатывает дважды сам по себе без нее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.in.read()` считывает только один символ. Но когда вы вводите ответ вы нажимаете букву и клавишу **Enter** (символ перевода строки). И оба этих символа попадают в поток.

Цикл извлекает из потока все символы, пока не встретит символ перевода строки.

Если цикл убрать, то первый вызов `read()` прочтет букву, а второй вызов `read()` прочтет перевод строки.